# wordpress.com RSS comment links

Tags: wordpress, rss, wordpress.com

Is there a way to remove/turn off the Comment link in a wordpress.com RSS feed? It gets added to the content tag and I can't seem to find any setting to turn this off.

its the **"http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/gocomments/dsordillo.wordpress.com/5/"** part of the following I want to remove.

```
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<p>testing 2</p><br /> <a rel="nofollow" href="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/gocomments/dsordillo.wordpress.com/5/"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/comments/dsordillo.wordpress.com/5/" /></a> <img alt="" border="0" src="https://pixel.wp.com/b.gif?host=dsordillo.wordpress.com&#038;blog=81136318&#038;post=5&#038;subd=dsordillo&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1" width="1" height="1" />
]]>
</content:encoded>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress Codex [contains some information on editing the RSS Feed output.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds) But I don´t think you are able to change the responsible files or add new ones when your blog is hosted by wordpress.com.